# Очень-очень оптимальный жадный алгоритм - C#

Tags: c#, алгоритм

Задача(у меня не совсем такая, она на другом языке, так что я просто привожу подобную).

Даны `n` заявок на проведение занятий в некоторой аудитории. В каждой заявке указаны начало и конец занятия **s<sub>i</sub>** и **f<sub>i</sub>** для `i`-й заявки). В случае пересечения заявок можно удовлетворить лишь одну из них. Заявки с номерами `i` и `j` совместны, если интервалы **(s<sub>i</sub>,f<sub>i</sub>)** и **(s<sub>j</sub>,f<sub>j</sub>)** не пересекаются (то есть **f<sub>i</sub> < f<sub>j</sub>** или **f<sub>j</sub> < f<sub>i</sub>**). Задача о выборе заявок состоит в том, чтобы набрать максимальное количество совместных друг с другом заявок. 
Количество заявок и сами заявки в текстовом документе prednasky.in, то-есть:

Ввод (текстовый документ):

> 5 - первая строчка - кол-во интервалов
>   2 4 (2 - начало интервала, 4 - конец и тд)
>   1 7
>   6 9
>   9 11
>   5 8

Вывод:

> 3 (максимальное количество совместных друг с другом заявок)
>   1 5 4 (номера этих заявок(если есть несколько вариантов - выписать любой))

Программу проверяет специальный сайт с тестами, и моя программа не проходит тесты на больших числах, хотя, как мне кажется я добился временной сложности **nlogn+n** (с памятью всё уже нормально, именно по скорости не проходит). Вот сам код:

```
     class Program
        {
                static int N;
               static int[,] a;

    static void Main(string[] args)

    {
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"prednasky.in"))
        {
            string line;
            line = sr.ReadLine();
            N = int.Parse(line);
            a = new int[N, 2];
            int[] indx = new int[N];
            int[] b = new int[N];
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            {
                line = sr.ReadLine();
                int[] nums = line.Trim().Split().Select(w => int.Parse(w)).ToArray();
                //начало интервалов и их идексы записываем в массив А
                a[i, 0] = nums[0];
                a[i, 1] = i + 1;
                //Концы интервалов записываем в массив б
                b[i] = nums[1];
                //заполняем массив индексов;
                indx[i] = i;
            }

            //Cортировка массива индексов по массиву б
            Array.Sort(b, indx);
            //Дальше одним циклом проходим массив а, но не по i, а по полю индексов (для того, что бы не сортировать двумерный массив, геморно же, лучше одномерный))            
            //string str = "";
            int last = 0;
            int poc = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            {
                if (a[indx[i], 0] > last)
                {
                    //в самое начало "отсортированного" массива записываем нужные числа по порядку
                    a[indx[poc], 0] = a[indx[i], 1];
                    poc++;
                    last = b[i];
                }
            }
            using (StreamWriter sr1 = new StreamWriter(@"rozvrh.out"))
            {
                sr1.WriteLine(poc);
                for (int i = 0; i < poc; i++)
                {
                    sr1.Write(a[indx[i], 0]);
                    sr1.Write(" ");
                }
                }
        }
    }

}
```

Алгоритм работает, проблема только со скоростью. Любым идеям буду рад)

Answer (score 3):

Можно отбирать среди оставшихся допустимых заявок ту, у которой время окончания наименьшее. В этом случае мы ничего не теряем.
Кроме того, следует удалять из очереди заявки, которые не могут быть использованы.

Алгоритм может быть рекурсивным, если вызываемая процедура получает допустимое начало интервала `$start`, очередь из оставшихся заявок `$queue` и массив принятых заявок `$request`.

Программа на PHP:

```
$request = [1=>[2,4], [1,7], [6,9], [9,11], [5,8]];
// starting shedule

function print_1d($text, $arr){
    echo "$text";
    foreach($arr as $value) printf("%2d ", $value);
}

function print_sh($text, $arr){
    echo "$text";
    foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
        if(gettype($value) == "array")  print_1d("&emsp;$key=> &emsp;", $value);
        else echo "&emsp;$key=>$value";
    }
}

function greedy($sh){
    global $request, $counter;
    $counter++;
    print_sh("<br>sh&nbsp;", $sh);
    $start = $sh['start'];
    $queue = $sh['queue'];
    $accepted = $sh['accepted'];
    if(empty($queue)) return $sh;
    foreach ($queue as $key=>$number) {
        if($request[$number][0] < $start) unset($queue[$key]);
        elseif(!isset($finish) || ($request[$number][1] < $finish)) {
            $finish = $request[$number][1];
            $keynext = $key;
        }
    }
    $start = $finish + 1;
    unset($queue[$keynext]);
    $accepted[] = $keynext+1;                       // then test the variant  
    return greedy(['start'=>$start, 'queue'=>$queue, 'accepted'=>$accepted]);   // when the request is accepted 
}

$n = count($request);
$counter = 0;
print_sh("The requests are:<br>",$request);
$shedule = [
    'start' => 0,
    'queue' => range(1, $n),
    'accepted'=>[]
];

echo "<br><br>The local optima are:<br>";
$shedule_opt = greedy($shedule);
print_sh("<br><br>Taking in account <b>$counter</b> variants.<br>The optimal variant is:<br>", $shedule_opt);
```

Результаты:

```
The requests are:
 1=>   2 4  2=>   1 7  3=>   6 9  4=>   9 11  5=>   5 8 

The local optima are:

sh  start=>0 queue=>   1 2 3 4 5  accepted=>  
sh  start=>5 queue=>   2 3 4 5  accepted=>   1 
sh  start=>9 queue=>   3 4  accepted=>   1 5 
sh  start=>12 queue=>   accepted=>   1 5 4 

Taking in account 4 variants.
The optimal variant is:
 start=>12 queue=>   accepted=>   1 5 4
```